# task in crontab does not work

Tags: cron, cron-task

I want to automatically start a program if it crashes (check if the process exists, if not, restart it), so using crontab is a simple solution, but

I creatd a simple crontab task using `crontab -e` or in `/etc/crontab` file like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

it doesn't work, it never launches `gnome-terminal`, I can see it executes the task in /var/log/syslog (Ubuntu) or /var/log/cron (CentOS), the gnome-terminal never comes up.

if you say since gnome-terminal is a gui program, then, this script to create bluetooth service won't work either :

using `crontab -e` or `/etc/crontab`:

```
* * * * * /home/username/run-bt
```

run-bt:

```
#!/bin/sh

# find bt pid
/usr/bin/pgrep bluetoothd
# if not running
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    /usr/sbin/service bluetooth restart
fi⏎
```

I already made the `run-bt` script executable, but bluetooth service won't start even if I stop the bluetooth service manually.

but this:

```
* * * * * /bin/ls > /tmp/ls.output
```

works as expected.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `crontab` does not load all the environment variables of the current user it runs for, just a few of them.

Maybe some of those environment variables are required by the scripts you try to run?

Comment: I'm just asking crob to execute `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`, what else environment variables does it need?

Comment: No idea... Anyway, why would you want gnome-terminal to be executed on a secondly basis???

Comment: It's just a very simple example to show the crob job doesn't work as expected.

Comment: First you could try `* * * * * /usr/bin/gnome-terminal >/tmp/mylog 2>&1` to see if the command triggers some error (all the outputs of `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` will be logged to the `/tmp/mylog` file).